# What does a void function with only ";" in code do?

Tags: c, pthreads

This might be a stupid question, but I really need to know since it's the first time I encounterd this:

```
    void function()
    {
    ;
    }
```

This is used in a thread based program with `pthread`. I want to know what it actually does.
I tried looking it up, but I don't even know how to google it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In short it does nothing.. Enter the function and exits .. Curious to know when this function is called

Comment: It is used in the Dining Philosopers problem. It's called in the pthread method. And thank you for your answer :D

Comment: But note that even if this function doesn't do anything the call to this has a stack overhead .. Since I don't see the whole code check why this is being called

Comment: @Gopi: There is no such thing as a "stack" in C. Your statement seems highly speculative. If this function were called from within its translation unit, a decent compiler would probably not emit any code at all.

Comment: @KerrekSB Agree !! I had a thought that compiler will optimize this code out. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`;` is a C statement termination construct. Placing it without statement is meaningless and doesn't hurt in code behavior in anyways. In your case, function gets called and returns.

Comment: The technical term is `null statement`, btw.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't do anything. And the `;` is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks, `;` whas the one giving me question marks. :D

Answer (score 1):

it does nothing in its current form. maybe for future implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It does nothing.  Most decent C compilers will most likely not even output code for a function like this.  Where did you see this?

Comment: it was in a solution for the Dinning Philosophers Problem.